# get dynamic value from a variable

Tags: php, loops

I need your help in this case:

I have these variables:

```
$precio_1 = 100.00;
$precio_2 = 150.00;
$precio_3 = 231.50;
$precio_4 = 458.44;
$precio_5 = 123.15;
```

Now I need to show them in an input form dynamically but I don't know how to get the variables values. I have this:

```
<?php
   for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++)
   {
     //Here I want to do the macrosustitution.
     $precio = 'precio_'.$i;
   ?>
     <label>Precio <?php echo $i;?></label>
     <input type="text" name="<?php echo $precio; ?>" value="<?php echo $precio; ?>"/>
   <?php        
   }
?>
```

I want theirs names like this : precio_1, precio_2, etc
and theirs values: 100.00, 150.00, etc.

Thank you every one and please forgive my writting and poor php knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have a trouble to maintain all those variables as your application scales.. Use an array instead and name the keys in such a way like this..

```
$arr = array('precio_1' => 100.00, 'precio_2' => 150.00);
```

So you could easily access them like..

```
echo $arr['precio_1']; 
echo $arr['precio_2'];
```

So on..

#### You could also use an `extract()` on your array

```
<?php
$arr = array('precio_1' => 100.00, 'precio_2' => 150.00);
extract($arr);
echo $precio_1; //"prints" 100.00
```

#### Using a `foreach` to make things easier....

```
<?php
$arr = array('precio_1' => 100.00, 'precio_2' => 150.00);
$i=0;
foreach($arr as $k=>$v)
{
    ?>
    <label>Precio <?php echo ++$i;?></label>
    <input type="text" name="<?php echo $arr[$k]; ?>" value="<?php echo $arr[$k]; ?>"/>
<?php
}
?>
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

[image]

Comment: Thank you Master Shankar Damodaran! I used your example and worked pretty good. But can you explain me the sample? because I got confused with ++$i variable and $k=>$v ???. Thanks!

Comment: @user3552695, Sure. `++$i;` is a pre-increment operator , When `$i=0` and if you do `echo $i++;` it will print 0, ( as this is called post increment operator. If you did `echo ++$i;` then it will print 1 as this is called a pre-increment operator. Read more here http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

Comment: Regarding the `foreach` , The `$k=>$v` represents the key and value of the corresponding array. For each iteration the they will be changing... In the first iteration , the value of `$k` will be `precio_1` and `$v` will be `100`.

Answer (score 1):

Here you could use a named variable:

here is what would work for you:

```
<?php

$precio_1 = 100.00;
$precio_2 = 150.00;
$precio_3 = 231.50;
$precio_4 = 458.44;
$precio_5 = 123.15;

   for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++)
   {
     //Here I want to do the macrosustitution.
     $p = 'precio_'.$i;
     $precio = $$p; // use a named variable
   ?>
     <label>Precio <?php echo $i;?></label>
     <input type="text" name="<?php echo $precio; ?>" value="<?php echo $precio; ?>"/>
   <?php        
   }
?>
```

A working PHP example [here](http://3v4l.org/guStF).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$arr = array('precio_1' => 100.00, 'precio_2' => 150.00, 'precio_3' => 231.50, 'precio_4' => 458.44, 'precio_5' => 123.15);

for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++){
$precio = 'precio_'.$i;
<label>Precio <?php echo $i;?></label>
     <input type="text" name="<?php echo $precio; ?>" value="<?php echo $arr[$i]; ?>"/>

}
```